What mathematical modelling was done to justified the asymmetric "k" for under 18s in the rating system used by the English Chess Federation?
In the English Chess Federation (ECF) implementation of Elo, an under 18 player gets a K of 40 when improving but a K of 20 when not.   This is a nice simple solution to young players improving faster then a rating system can track, but what is the mathematical justification for it?
See https://www.ecfrating.org.uk/v2/help/help_rating.php
If age >= 18 or New Rating < Old Rating
= 700 / No. of Games This Month
if (20 x No. of Games this month) > 700
= 20 otherwise
If age < 18 and New Rating > Old Rating
= 700 / No. of Games This Month
if (40 x No. of Games this month) > 700
= 40 otherwise

(I find the US system of giving a bonus when a player does a lot better then expected easyer to justify as it likely to be "self correcting".  But it is much more complex.)
